# Show only element when we have focused in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how should I make a question to ask all of you , but I will try to explain. My question is that I would like to show element with which I have hidden in CSS , in my code there are same class container and result class

My expectation when I focus on the text 1 it should be shown only result of text 1 and text 2 will not make an action.

```js
$('.examples').focus(function() {
    $('div.example').show();
    $(document).bind('focusin.example click.example',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.example, .examples').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.example');
        $('div.example').fadeOut('medium');
    });
});
$('div.example').hide();
```

```css
.example{
 background: gray;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<label for="example">Text 1:</label>
<input class="examples" name="example" type="text" maxlength="100" />
    <div class="example">
        <p>reuslt</p>
    </div>
</p>
<br />
<label for="example">Text2:</label>
<input class="examples" name="example" type="text" maxlength="100" />
    <div class="example">
        <p>result</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I edited your question to take advantage of Stack Overflow's code snippet feature. If this is against your intent feel free to revert.

Comment: My expectation when..... can you please make it a little clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You html has a `div` in a `p` element which is not value, so use `div` instead of `p` as the container, then you need to show the next `div.example` of the `focus`ed `input` so

```js
$('.examples').focus(function() {
    $(this).next('div.example').show();
    $(document).bind('focusin.example click.example',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.example, .examples').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.example');
        $('div.example').fadeOut('medium');
    });
});
$('div.example').hide();
```

```css
.example{
 background: gray;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label for="example">Text 1:</label>
<input class="examples" name="example" type="text" maxlength="100" />
    <div class="example">
        <p>reuslt</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<label for="example">Text2:</label>
<input class="examples" name="example" type="text" maxlength="100" />
    <div class="example">
        <p>result</p>
    </div>
```